# Finding path of zero/Negative weight between Two Nodes on Graph by Utilizing Negative Cycles

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, backtracking, weighted

I really struggled with describing this in the title but I'll give it a go in a longer format.

I'm really stumped on this problem and I'm not looking for answers, just a little help or some specific topics to read up on.

What I have is a directed Graph with edges of various weights, both negative and positive. What I am attempting to do is to write an algorithm that is provided with two nodes positioned on the graph (and assuming they're connected) finds a path between them that results in the total weight of the path being either zero or negative. The path can include nodes multiple times (hopefully allowing for the path to offset the positive weight of included edges).

I'm currently reading Russel and Norvig's Artificial Intelligence, but am struggling to find a way to apply the logic in the text to my problem due to various problems (The algorithm continuously going round the negative cycle). I'm not fully understanding how to utilize methods such as Backtrack and AStar for this

If anyone could point me in the right direction of something that would help me understand my problem better it would be a great help, I'm fine with dealing with DFS and BFS and many other things in relation to Graphs but having to find a path between two nodes with the weight restrictions is really baffling me.

Thanks

Below I've included a sample graph, I need to be able to find a path from Start to Goal where the total weight of the path doesn't exceed Zero.

Example Graph
http://i144.photobucket.com/albums/r166/ZooropaTV/bu.jpg

*Just realised that a lot of the searching/Reading I've been doing has been misguided, since my goal isn't necessarily about finding the shortest path by weight, but by visiting the minimum required number of nodes, I need to have another think about it now, but still would like any advice*

Comment: The book `Network Flows: Theory, Algorithms, and Applications` might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: The Floyd–Warshall algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

You'll have to modify it to fit your needs but it will detect negative cycles thus allowing you to find a path of zero or lesser weight.